# Locking a table for inserts from a MySQL InnoDB Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concurrency, innodb

I am writing a stored procedure. In it I have the following mysql insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO `Address`(`countryCode`, `addressLine1`, `addressLine2`, `postcode`, `region`, `city`) VALUES (country, addressLine1, addressLine2, postcode, region, city);
INSERT INTO `UserAddress`(`username`, `creationDate`, `addressId`) VALUES (username,NOW(),(SELECT addressId FROM Address ORDER BY addressId DESC LIMIT 1));
```

As you can see, I'm performing an insert on an Address table, and then use the auto incremented "addressId" in the subquery on the next line. Now, if between these 2 statements another transaction would insert something into the Address table I would insert the wrong addressId into the UserAddress table. My guess would be I need to lock the Address table while these statements are being executed.

After a long search I found the following code to lock the Address table:

```
SELECT addressId FROM Address FOR UPDATE;
```

Would this also work for newly inserted rows? If not, what would?

Comment: Will you always be inserting the two rows together? If so, why inserting them in separate tables? I think your design has a problem.

Comment: If you really need to do this,I might think about using a transaction.  But as @GurV says, you might have a design problem.

Comment: @GurV How is it a design problem? The idea is that users can have multiple addresses. Also, one address can be of multiple users. Also, an adress has an creation date. I would need a table in between the Address and User tables then right?

Comment: The code, _as written_, only handles 1:1.  It does not allow for 1:many, nor for many:1, nor many:many.  You need IODKU, a unique key, and/or a mapping table for those.

Comment: There is a many to many relationship between User and Address. The table in between is UserAddress. That is still possible with my code right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly why they invented a [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html)

```
INSERT INTO `Address`(`countryCode`, `addressLine1`, `addressLine2`, `postcode`, `region`, `city`) VALUES (country, addressLine1, addressLine2, postcode, region, city);
INSERT INTO `UserAddress`(`username`, `creationDate`, `addressId`) VALUES (username,NOW(),LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

No need for locks or transactions or even stored procedures for the task of grabbing the last id. Just do this in your app.

Comment: And that's concurrency safe? Awesome!

Comment: glad to have helped

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is local to the connection; hence, "currency safe".

Comment: But I disagree on not needing a 'transaction'.  Without such, you could get the `Address` stored but not the `UserAddress`, if the server crashes between the two autocommited `INSERTs`.

Comment: Yes, @RickJames has a point about transaction. In my answer though, I was talking purely in context of grabbing the ID of the last insert.

Comment: Thanks for your ellaboration @Rick

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should do it inside a `Transaction`, by using 'START TRANSACTION;' and 'COMMIT' syntax. You also need to set `autocommit` to 0 (it is enabled by default). [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) is the documentation for Transactions and autocommit.

As long as your updates are wrapped inside a transaction and appropriate [isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_isolation_level) is set, changes made by other transaction will not affect your transaction.

Comment: Is it good design to wrap every of my stored procedures in a START TRANSACTION;' and 'COMMIT within the procedure?

Comment: Not everything but the bits which need isolation, like the one you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Think of it this way... In this:  Query 1: take some money out of your bank account; Query 2: put that money in your savings account.  What if the server crashed between query 1 and query 2?  That is the classic example of needing `BEGIN; query 1; query 2; COMMIT;` so that either _both_ succeed or _neither_.  If your app has something like that, you need transactions.